# Zabbix icmp pinger processes more than 75% busy

Tags: zabbix

In my zabbix server I have this error.

> Zabbix icmp pinger processes more than 75% busy

Anybody have some advice how fix it?

Regards

Comment: O.k I found how fix it.

http://it.kuchuk.net/2013/04/zabbix.html

Answer (score 6):

The answer from Mick's comment:

**Problem**: Zabbix proxy poller processes more than 75% busy

**Solution**: In zabbix_server.conf

> StartPollers=20

**Problem**: Zabbix icmp pinger processes more than 75% busy

**Solution**: In zabbix_server.conf

> StartPingers=10
>   StartDiscoverers=10

**Problem**: Zabbix unreachable poller processes more than 75% busy

**Solution**: In zabbix_server.conf

> StartPollersUnreachable=10